# How do I turn returned python JSON dictionary in a list in dictionary, data into a SQL insert

Tags: python, sql, json, api, dictionary

Given example JSON data that has a Dictionary and within it a List containing another dictionary set of Key pairs:

```
MyData={
    'Key1': 'Value 1', 
    'Key2': Value2, 
    'Key3': Value3, 
    'Key4': 
            [
            {
              "SubKey1": "SubValue",
              "SubKey2": "SubValue",
              "SubKey3": "SubValue",
              "SubKey1": "SubValue"
            },
            {
              "SubKey1": "SubValue",
              "SubKey2": "SubValue",
              "SubKey3": "SubValue",
              "SubKey1": "SubValue"
            },
            {
              "SubKey1": "SubValue",
              "SubKey2": "SubValue",
              "SubKey3": "SubValue",
              "SubKey1": "SubValue"
            }
          ]
        }
```

How would I turn this into a proper SQL insert?

I found a SQL that would do a single insert and it seems to work well:

```
columns = ', '.join("'" + str(x).replace('/', '_') + "'" for x in MyData.keys())
values = ', '.join("'" + str(x).replace('/', '_') + "'" for x in MyData.values())
sql = "INSERT INTO %s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s );" % ('mytable', columns, values)
print(sql)
```

But it  only create a 1 row insert where

What I'm looking for is Key1,Key2,Key3 inserted 3 times along with the 3 subvalues (note there can be more or less than 3).

I'll note this is a Python 3 call to an API returning JSON data.

Thanks

Comment: What does the table structure look like? It seems like `Key4` should be in another table with a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Assuming your table has key1, key2 and key3 columns your data would only create one row i.e. your final query would look something like **insert into mytable (key1, key2 and key3) values('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3',)**  
Why would you expect 3 inserts? Share your table structure..

Comment: Good point, Key4 value can be in a separate table. So in that case how would I accomplish inserting the 3 Key values, grabbing the SQL local KeyID and creating the inserts along with the foreign key in the new table?

I can make the table structure what I want but given what we've spoken of here it's something along the lines of 2 tables with table1 having 3 columns and table2 having 5 columns one being the foreign key.

I'd also like to have inserted Ids and datetime stamps. The Ids can be auto increment but not sure about the timestamps using these methods (usually it's just getdate().

Answer (score 0):

For the record what I will do is go back to my original SQL insert method, use a SQL connection created through Python and create a single insert for the 1st table. Then iterate through the key4 value and created inserts for the 2nd table (this way it will dynamically insert my rows depending on the count of returned values.

Something like this:

Create my connection

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=.\........;'
                          'Database=MyDatabase;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
                    @InsertSQLVariable (insert into MyTable values .... )
                    ''')
    conn.commit()
```

Then I will pass @InsertSQLVariable above created as mentioned above:

```
print("insert into Table1 values ('",\
      MyData["Key1"],"',",\
      MyData["Key2"],")",\
      MyData["Key2"],"'",\
      sep='')
```

Then as mentioned iterate through the key value and created inserts for the 2nd table:

```
for i in MyData["Key4"]:
    print("insert into Table2 values ('",\
          i["SubKey1"],"',",\
          i["SubKey2"],"',",\
          i["SubKey3"],"',",\
          i["SubKey4"],"',",\
          sep='')
```

A Few notes to add:

- This line: sep='' - removes the space at the end of the python print function, I will likely have to remove it once setting it to a variable.
- As I type I realize that in the 2nd table query I still need to get the Identity from the 1st table insert in order to have the keys to the tables.
- I've used print instead of a SQLInsert variable only to demonstrate that I will be able to create my insert statements successfully.
- The SQL insert syntax needs is pretty rough and definitely still off as I'm still building it but I think I have enough to show I am able to accomplish my needs at this point. I wanted to complete this post to support StackOverflow since they have helped me out on occasion in the past...you may see me again in the near future :)

My thanks to StackOverflow and all who contribute to it.